# VB.Net Excel Formula Range Dynamically?

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-formula

Hi I want to make a dynamic Range inside the Excel SUMIFS Formula using Vb.net.

Here's my code

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim wsCopyHere as Worksheet 'All Worksheet and Workbooks are correct
Dim dueValue, lRow, bidRow as long
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row()
bidRow = lRow + 18
dueValue = bidRow + 1
With wsCopyHere.Range("J" & bidRow + 1)
    .Formula = "= SUMIFS(J20: J ""dueValue"", I19: I35, I39, H19: H35, K39)"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True
End With
```

Here's the other method I used which is returns nothing

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim wsCopyHere as Worksheet 'All Worksheet and Workbooks are correct
Dim dueValue, lRow, bidRow as long    
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row()
bidRow = lRow + 18
dueValue = bidRow + 1
With wsCopyHere.Range("J" & bidRow + 1)
    .Value = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(wsCopyHere.Range("J20:J" & dueValue), wsCopyHere.Range("I20:I" & dueValue), wsCopyHere.Range("I" & dueValue), wsCopyHere.Range("H20:H" & dueValue), wsCopyHere.Range("K" & dueValue))
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = True
End With
```

Thank you Cheers

Comment: From your code the value of `dueValue` will be 1.  It's not clear why you're not using `lRow` there.

Comment: the value of bidRow = lRow + 18 .  I did not use the lRow because there is a existing data on that cell. I want to put the data on the last cell.

Comment: In *the code you posted* `dueValue` has a value of 1

Comment: Apologies, I already edit my code.